# How to Intent Kt file from other folder?

Tags: android, kotlin

You can see the Picture in the question, I have to intent to access the file from MainActivity to the auth.PhoneValidation activity
[This code in MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20P1w.png)

[I have to intent PhoneValidation under the auth  folder,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I36at.png)

Please help me out.

```
var intent = Intent(this, auth.PhoneValidation :: class.java)
```

Comment: I use             var intent = Intent(this, com.help.ridewithme.auth.PhoneValidation :: class.java)
 but is any way to reduce the text of com.help.ridewithme ?

Comment: If I use R then it show me Error on auth "var intent = Intent(this, R.auth.PhoneValidation :: class.java)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var intent = Intent(this, PhoneValidation :: class.java)

just remove "auth." and make sure your PhoneValidation is registered in Manifest file

Comment: In Menifest file i added the one         <activity android:name=".auth.PhoneValidation"></activity>
           In the main activity, I remove the auth  but still, I get an error in this line var intent = Intent(this, PhoneValidation :: class.java)

Comment: I got the solution which is just imports the file import com.help.ridewithme.auth.PhoneAuthActivity in mainactivtly which help to which help me to use that var intent = Intent(this, PhoneValidation:: class.java)